# Convert command line cURL to C cURL

Tags: curl, solr

I've never done any `Curl` before so am in need of some help. I've tried to work this out from examples but cannot get my head around it!

I have a curl command that I can successfully run from a windows command line that index PDF file in `Solr`.

I would need to incorporate this `curl` command in a C client.

How can I translate this Curl command so that it works in a `C Curl client`?

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=doc2&uprefix=attr_&fmap.content=attr_content&commit=true"" -F "myfile=@doc.pdf"
```

Comment: Do you intend to call the cURL executable from your C client, or to use libcurl?

Comment: Yes I intended to call cURL executables from my C client.

Answer (score 12):

At FOSDEM 2015, the writer of curl -Daniel Stenberg- showed me a nice example using the libcurl option:

```
curl http://example.com --libcurl example.c
```

As you can guess you can find the full code (incl. handler and cleanup) in example.c

Answer (score 0):

```
STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(STARTUPINFO) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
TCHAR tempCmdLine[MAX_PATH];
_tcscpy_s(tempCmdLine, MAX_PATH, _T("curl.exe http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=doc2&uprefix=attr_&fmap.content=attr_content&commit=true -F myfile=@doc.pdf"));
CreateProcess(NULL, tempCmdLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

You may want to check the return value of `CreateProcess`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. 
If I want to execute same thing by using cURL API curl_easy_init, curl_easy_setopt, curl_easy_perform and curl_easy_cleanup. Then How would I achieve this?

Comment: I have tried using httpput.c.
It is giving me following error message can you please help why? <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 400 </title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR: 400</h2><pre>Unsupported method: PUT</pre>
<p>RequestURI=/solr/update/extract/</p><p><i><small><a href="http://jetty.mortbay.org/">Powered by Jetty://</a></small></i></p><br/>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

</body>
</html>

Comment: The error message seems to indicate the file upload using HTTP PUT is not allowed. Does it work when running cURL from the command line?

Comment: curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=doc2&uprefix=attr_&fmap.content=attr_content&commit=true"" -F "myfile=@doc.pdf" it works fine when I run it through command prompt

Comment: hd = open("doc1.pdf", O_RDONLY) ;
  fstat(hd, &file_info);
  close(hd) ; hd_src = fopen("doc1.pdf", "rb");
 
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
 
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_callback);curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1L);

Comment: curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract/");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, hd_src);curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t)file_info.st_size);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

Comment: curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "literal.id=doc2&uprefix=attr_&fmap.content=attr_content&commit=true"); 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t)-1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writefunc);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &s);

Comment: What happens if you add `-X POST` ?

Comment: Don't use `CURLOPT_PUT`, try `CURLOPT_POST`.

Comment: Sorry, Now HTTP error is not coming (When I comment CURLOPT_UPLOAD also) but the file is not getting indexed in Solr... Or it is not getting uploaded to the Solr server

Comment: Thank you Daniel.
 There is --libcurl <File> command line option for curl.exe to generate c CURL code which is being used by cURl command. By referring generated code I am able to index file in Solr.